# Core Data app crashes on saving

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nscoding

I got the following error `[context save:&error]`. How should I fix?

> unrecognized selector sent to class
>   *** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had -finishEncoding called on it.
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[TempObject encodeWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to class'

Here the code I'm using.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
PostRequest *postRequestObject = (PostRequest *)[NSEntityDescription   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PostRequest" inManagedObjectContext:context];

DummyClass *request = OtherClassObject;
postRequestObject.request = request;
// request is attribute with type transformable
NSLog(@"requestpost data -> %@",postRequestObject.request);

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

#pragma mark - private method
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PostRequest" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:80];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"status" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [sortDescriptor autorelease];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"root"] autorelease];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Is this discussion the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072849/core-data-unresolved-error-app-crashs-on-save? If so, delete this question (or the previous), please.

Comment: And **context could be useful**. What data are you trying to save?

Comment: Data is request with parameters.

Comment: What is `TempObject` and how are you using it? It's in your error message but doesn't show up anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi @TomHarrington TempObject is class which is is imported in the current controller. In TempObject <NSCoding> is used.

Comment: Your error message says that `TempObject` does not in fact support `NSCoding`.

Comment: The fact that you have deleted your previous question and posted this again is probably about to cause you to be banned from asking questions here at all. Just FYI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that you have a class named `TempObject`, that you're trying to call `encodeWithCoder:` on it, and that this class does not implement that method. That's a crashing bug, as you're seeing.

It seems that you have a transformable Core Data attribute somewhere, and that you're assigning an instance of `TempObject` to this attribute. I don't know where that is. Your code snippet mentions a transformable attribute, but you don't use `TempObject` in the code. I can't tell if this code is not actually the cause of the crash or if you changed the name by hand for some reason.

*Anyway*, when you have a transformable attribute, you must do one of two things:

1. Make your class conform to `NSCoding`. You said in a comment that you did, but your error message says that you didn't-- or at least, that you didn't finish the job. `NSCoding` defines two methods, `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`, and your class must implement both of them.
2. Create a custom `NSValueTransformer` subclass that can convert your object to/from `NSData`, and configure your Core Data model to use this. Apple provides a couple of really good (but simple) examples of how to do this.

Anything you assign to a transformable attribute **must** do one of these. Which one is up to you.

It **seems** that you're trying to do #1 but haven't finished the job. Make sure that your class conforms to `NSCoding`.